# How to display calculation of html table on another column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, laravel

I have 3 columns, one column `total_column_price` uses to display the calculation result of `amount` and `device_price`. How to achieve that?

**The Table**

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'TransactionsINController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) }}

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Device Price</th>
            <th><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm addRow">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </a>
            </th>
            <th>Column Total Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::number('amount[]', 'value', ['name' => 'amount[]']) }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::number('device_price[]', 'value', ['name' => 'device_price[]']) }}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ Form::text('total_column_price', '') }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total: </td>
            <td style="border: none"><b class="total_price"></b></td>
            <td style="border: none"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

{{ Form::button('<i class="far fa-save"></i> Submit', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-info'] )  }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

This is the calculation I try to use. the purpose is when I make input in `amount` and `device_price` column the result will automatically appear in `total_column_price`.

**The Script to Calculate**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('tbody').delegate('.amount,.device_price','keyup',function(){
            var tr=$(this).parent().parent();
            var amount=tr.find('.amount').val();
            var device_price=tr.find('.device_price').val();
            var total_column_price=(amount*device_price);
            tr.find(.total_column_price).val(total_column_price);
            total_price();
        });
        function total_price(){
            var total_price=0;
            $('.total_column_price').each(function(i,e){
                var total_column_price=$(this).val()-0;
            total_price +=total_column_price;
        });
            $('.total_price').html(total_price+",00");
        }
</script>
```

Comment: I can't be 100% sure as your Form fields are not displayed as html in your snippet, but I think you are referring to them as a class instead of their input field name. Try referring to the values like this instead $('input[name="amount"]'). Secondly the amount and device_price fields seems to be specified as an array, but you are treating them as a singular number. Try starting there.

Comment: @RyanN. yes this is a dynamic table where i can add/remove rows. I dont really understand what are you referring to since I'm new to web and laravel. I add the form please review it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to be good in your code the problem is way you are using the JQuery find function, you need to add quotes while entering the selector.

```
 tr.find('.total_column_price').val(total_column_price);
```

**Use the new event handle .on()
The .on() syntax is the new syntax that version 1.7 uses and it is meant to substitute .bind(), .delegate() and .live().**

Another problem in your javascript was related to fetching the  parent from on keyup in  input box.
It should be like this

```
var tr = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
```

Try the code below:

```
 $(function() {

  $(document).on('keyup', 'input[name="amount[]"],input[name="device_price[]"]', function() {
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    var amount = tr.find('input[name="amount[]"]').val();
    var device_price = tr.find('input[name="device_price[]"]').val();
    var total_column_price = (amount * device_price);
    total_price();
  });

  function total_price() {
    var total_price = 0;
    $('input[name="total_column_price[]"]').each(function(i, e) {
      var total_column_price = $(this).val() - 0;
      total_price += total_column_price;
    });
    $('.total_price').html(total_price + ",00");
  }


})
```

Comment: use  $(document) check the code above changes done, this will bind the event for complete page and dynamic elements

Comment: Can you please add the output html code which your code is generating, so we can know the selector used is right or not!

Comment: get the code which is rendered in your website page. Let have converstaion over chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201294/room-for-rishab-and-aditya

Comment: Hi i have updated code and tested it is working please replace with your code base